# Output of cosine_similarity() not as expected (all values equal to 1.)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I have been trying to find cosine similarity between the vector representation of the tag of a movie (computed using average word2vec) and all the other movies's vector representation (also using avg word2vec).

But the output always comes out to be `1.` somehow, even when I pass in to both parameters of the cosine_similarity function as the vector representation of movies itself.

Code for generation of avg word2vec

```py
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(window=10, min_count=1, workers=8, vector_size=300, alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.0007)
model.build_vocab(flatten_corpus) #flatten_corpus is basically the corpus
model.train(flatten_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=10)
embeddings = model.wv.get_normed_vectors()
```

Here the output of the embedding of every word->

```py
array([[-0.01744956, -0.11224882,  0.13236344, ...,  0.0972883 ,
         0.02966034, -0.04626285],
       [ 0.05841004, -0.00941145, -0.07332838, ..., -0.07433803,
         0.02825699, -0.12789766],
       [ 0.10318288, -0.08702228, -0.14564443, ...,  0.1026295 ,
         0.01967871,  0.03213153],
       ...,
       [-0.03165161,  0.08460254, -0.05135883, ..., -0.00983593,
         0.08976564,  0.01239256],
       [-0.04694653,  0.12579133, -0.03276197, ..., -0.02105372,
         0.08431913, -0.0318971 ],
       [ 0.03841057,  0.03328352, -0.05580311, ...,  0.04187248,
        -0.03482581, -0.02766625]], dtype=float32)
```

Here''s how I computed the Avg Word2Vec->

```py
ls = []
avg_embeddings = []
for i in range(len(flatten_corpus)):
    
    if len(flatten_corpus[i]) != 0:
    
        for j in range(len(flatten_corpus[i])):

            if len(flatten_corpus[j]) != 0:

                if len(flatten_corpus[i][j]) != 0:
                    ls.append(model.wv[flatten_corpus[i][j]].tolist())


        ls = list(chain.from_iterable(ls))

        avg_embeddings.append(sum(ls)/len(flatten_corpus[i]))
        ls = []
```

Now when I try the similarity function i get this->

Code

```py
cosine_similarity(np.array(avg_embeddings[idx]).reshape(1, -1), np.array(avg_embeddings).reshape(1, -1))
```

Error->

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[702], line 1
----> 1 cosine_similarity(np.array(avg_embeddings[idx]).reshape(1, -1), np.array(avg_embeddings).reshape(1, -1))

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py:1393, in cosine_similarity(X, Y, dense_output)
   1358 """Compute cosine similarity between samples in X and Y.
   1359 
   1360 Cosine similarity, or the cosine kernel, computes similarity as the
   (...)
   1389     Returns the cosine similarity between samples in X and Y.
   1390 """
   1391 # to avoid recursive import
-> 1393 X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
   1395 X_normalized = normalize(X, copy=True)
   1396 if X is Y:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py:180, in check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y, precomputed, dtype, accept_sparse, force_all_finite, copy)
    174         raise ValueError(
    175             "Precomputed metric requires shape "
    176             "(n_queries, n_indexed). Got (%d, %d) "
    177             "for %d indexed." % (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], Y.shape[0])
    178         )
    179 elif X.shape[1] != Y.shape[1]:
--> 180     raise ValueError(
    181         "Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: "
    182         "X.shape[1] == %d while Y.shape[1] == %d" % (X.shape[1], Y.shape[1])
    183     )
    185 return X, Y

ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 1 while Y.shape[1] == 4881
```

When i pass both parameters as avg_embeddings then i get this->

```py
array([[1.]])  #just this and not the similarity values, it should been 4886 since these are the total no of movies present
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you not want to transpose your second matrix in the cosine similarity function?

Comment: There are also better and more structured scripts to create the average embedding for each element of your corpus... Using one of these may solve your dimension issues. You want to have a matrix A of dimension (n_sample, vector_dim) and matrix B (vector_dim, n_sample). Check this before applying the cosine similarity function.

Comment: HI @Simi. I did as you said ->cosine_similarity(np.array(avg_embeddings).reshape(1, -1).T, np.array(avg_embeddings).reshape(1, -1).T)

Comment: But got this-> array([[ 1.,  1., -1., ...,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1., ...,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1., ..., -1.,  1., -1.],
       ...,
       [ 1.,  1., -1., ...,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1., ..., -1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1., ...,  1., -1.,  1.]])

Comment: You should only transpose the second matrix, not both. Check if the shapes of the matrices match with my second comment. Can you also share the shape of the first, second an result matrix?

Comment: Given that you only have 1 and -1 as a result also makes me believe that you are currently not computing the average embedding correctly.

Comment: Glad your main problem was resolved! As separate notes: (1) using `min_count=1` almost always makes Word2Vec models worse than higher values, such as the default `min_count=5` or (if you have enough data) even larger values. (2) there's usually no good reason from using arbitrary non-default alph values like `alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.0007` - instead it's often the mark of people (including those writing online tutorials/examples) copying nonsense choices with no understanding. (If you got these from an online example, there's a good chance that's a **bad** online example.)

Comment: Oh thank you @gojomo. I did copied from an article, thought it improve my model. I'll make sure that understand it's importance and play around with it's values in the future.